# How to open external H2DB driver with Java ClassLoader?

Tags: java, classloader, h2

I want to load h2 database driver while my application is loading. I using URLClassLoader to load the external library into classpath, but i give the following error:

```
19:25:56 [SEVERE] java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:h2:x\y\store.h2db
19:25:56 [SEVERE]       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
19:25:56 [SEVERE]       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

I use this code to loading my lib:

```
File myJar = new File("./lib/h2.jar");
URL url = myJar.toURL();  
URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Driver drv = (Driver) Class.forName("org.h2.Driver", true, cl).newInstance();
DriverManager.registerDriver(drv);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried using absolute path instead of relative?

Comment: The class loaded perfectly, the problem in driver registery. When I try this: `System.out.println(drv.toString());` it return: org.h2.Driver@xyxyxyxy

Comment: why do you use URLClassLoader? I'm pretty sure that if you just user Class.forName("org.h2.Driver") the driver gets loaded (and when loaded it automatically self registers to the DriverManager, so you don't need to instantiate it with newInstance(), nor to call registerDriver().

Comment: btw, your code looks correct to me; have you tried to debug the DriverManager during the registerDriver() and during the getConnection()?

Comment: You shouldn't edit the answer in the code but write a real answer instead.

Comment: Good solution. Since `addURL()` accessibility is `protected` you could have overridden it in a subclass of `URLClassLoader`, making the method `public` instead of using reflection; but still, it's minor cosmetic :). *Update*: forget about it... I just noticed you call the method on the SystemClassLoader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I found the solution, use the following code to load a JAR file, or classes.

```
private void loadExternalDriver(File file) throws Exception {
    Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), new Object[]{file.toURI().toURL()});
}
```

In my example:

```
File driver = new File("./lib/h2.jar");
this.loadExternalDriver(driver);
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
```

It works very well. Thanks for any help.